# Magento - Text Input on Grouped Product

Tags: magento

I am trying to create a grouped product in Magento where the customer must choose the product and  fill out a text field before adding the item to the cart. I know I can do this by simply creating one product and adding custom options, but the problem with that is that I need to be able to control the stock of each product configuration. I read that I can just use the custom options field for every individual item in the grouped product and as long as it isn't a required field it will work, but that does not work for me. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for this also, and the quickest solution appears to be this 3rd party module:

http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/catalog-enhancements/grouped-options.html

the module author provides background on how they did it here:

http://www.brimllc.com/2010/07/magento-associating-simple-products-with-required-options-to-a-grouped-product/